# A quiz to practice some of the notion of the chapter four of app development with swift

Tags: swift, quiz, cocoa

I just want feedback about the code. Better implementation, more commentary etc.

[image: The first storyboard]

[image: Second storyboard]

- app Delegate.swift

  ```
  import UIKit



  @UIApplicationMain
  class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

      var window: UIWindow?


      func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
          // Override point for customization after application launch.
          let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

          let savedResultVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SavedResultViewController") as? SavesResultsTableViewController
          let introductionVC = window?.rootViewController as? IntroductionViewController
          introductionVC?.delegate = savedResultVC


          return true
      }
  ```
- Introduction view controller

  ```
  import UIKit

  class IntroductionViewController: UIViewController{
      var delegate: SavesResultsTableViewControllerDelegate?

      @IBOutlet weak var matematicQuizButton: UIButton!
      @IBOutlet weak var montryQuizButton: UIButton!
      override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
          delegate?.setResult(result: nil)
          // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
      }
      override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
      {

          if segue.identifier == "ContryQuizSegue"
          {
              let navigationController = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
              let quizViewController = navigationController.topViewController as! QuizViewController
              quizViewController.matematicalQuizIsHidden = true
          }


      }
      @IBAction func unwindResultToMenue(unwindSegue: UIStoryboardSegue)
      {
      }
      @IBAction func unwindSavedResultToMenue(unwindSegue: UIStoryboardSegue)
      {
      }
  ```
- QuizViewController

  ```
  import UIKit

  class QuizViewController: UIViewController {

      var matematicalExpressionAnswers = [MatematicalExpression]()
      var contryQuizAnswers = [Image_Contry]()
      var matematicalExpressionsNumber = 0
      var contrysNumber = 0
      var questionIndex = 1
      var timer = Timer()
      var time:Int = 0
      var matematicExpression:MatematicalExpression?
      var contry:Image_Contry?


      @IBOutlet weak var progressBar: UIProgressView!

      @IBOutlet weak var matematicalQuizStackview: UIStackView!
      @IBOutlet weak var contryQuizStackView: UIStackView!

      @IBOutlet weak var matematicalExpressionTimerLabel: UILabel!
      @IBOutlet weak var matematicalExpresionLabel: UILabel!
      @IBOutlet weak var matematicalExpressionTextField: UITextField!

      @IBOutlet weak var contryQuizTimerLabel: UILabel!
      @IBOutlet weak var contryQuizImageView: UIImageView!
      @IBOutlet var contryQuizAnswerChoicesButtons: [UIButton]!

      var matematicalQuizIsHidden:Bool?
      var matematicalExpressions:[MatematicalExpression] = [MatematicalExpression(expression: "2 × 2", answer: "4", playerCorectlyAnswered: false),
                                                            MatematicalExpression(expression: "5 + 2 × 6", answer: "17", playerCorectlyAnswered: false),
                                                            MatematicalExpression(expression: "6 - 3 × 8 ÷ 4", answer: "0", playerCorectlyAnswered: false),
                                                            MatematicalExpression(expression: "4 + 6 × 3 - 8", answer: "14", playerCorectlyAnswered: false),
                                                            MatematicalExpression(expression: "3 × 5 - 36 ÷ 4 + 1", answer: "7", playerCorectlyAnswered: false),
                                                            MatematicalExpression(expression: "5 + 3 - 9 × 2", answer: "-10", playerCorectlyAnswered: false)]
      // See pixeEb for image
      var contrys:[Image_Contry] = [Image_Contry(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Pyramide"), answer: "Égypte", answerPossibility:["Cuba","Inde","Brésil","Égypte"] ,playerCorectlyAnswered: false),
                                    Image_Contry(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Tour Eiffel"), answer: "France", answerPossibility: ["Angleterre","Russie","Allemagne","France"], playerCorectlyAnswered: false),
                                    Image_Contry(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Machu Picchu"),answer:"Perou", answerPossibility: [ "Chili","Chine","Asie","Perou"], playerCorectlyAnswered: false),
                                    Image_Contry(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Empire State Building"), answer: "Étas-Unis", answerPossibility: ["Mexique","Indonésie","Japon","Étas-Unis"], playerCorectlyAnswered: false),
                                    Image_Contry(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "gaspesie-1373018_1920"), answer: "Canada", answerPossibility: ["Grèce","Australie","Haïti","Canada"], playerCorectlyAnswered: false),
                                    Image_Contry(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "london-2393098_1920"), answer: "Angleterre", answerPossibility: ["Espagne","Italie","Corée du Sud","Angleterre"], playerCorectlyAnswered: false)]
      override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()

          if let hidden = matematicalQuizIsHidden
          {
              contrysNumber = contrys.count
              startContryTimer()
              matematicalQuizStackview.isHidden = hidden
              updateContryQuizUI()

          }
          else
          {
              matematicalExpressionsNumber = matematicalExpressions.count
              startMatematicalTimer()
              contryQuizStackView.isHidden = true
              updateMatematicalQuizUI()

          }

          // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
      }


      override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
          super.viewWillAppear(animated)

      }


      @IBAction func playerGuessedAnswerMatematicalExpression(_ sender: UITextField) {
          guard let answer = sender.text else {return}
          guard !answer.isEmpty else {return}

          sender.isEnabled = false

          if sender.text == matematicExpression?.answer
          {
              sender.textColor = UIColor.green
              matematicExpression?.playerCorectlyAnswered = true
              matematicalExpressionAnswers.append(matematicExpression!)


          }
          else
          {
              sender.textColor = UIColor.red
              matematicExpression?.playerCorectlyAnswered = false
              matematicalExpressionAnswers.append(matematicExpression!)
          }
          stopTimer()
          nextMatematicalExpression()
      }


      //UI matematicalQuizModification
      func updateMatematicalQuizUI() -> Bool
      {
          guard matematicalExpressions.isEmpty == false else {return false}

          let number = Int.random(in: 0...matematicalExpressions.count - 1)
          matematicExpression = matematicalExpressions.remove(at: number)
          matematicalExpresionLabel.text = matematicExpression?.expression
          let totalProgress = Float(self.questionIndex)/Float(self.matematicalExpressionsNumber)
          self.progressBar.setProgress(totalProgress, animated: true)
          return true
      }

      func nextMatematicalExpression()
      {

          DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2)
          {

              self.questionIndex += 1
              self.matematicalExpressionTimerLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
              self.matematicalExpressionTextField.textColor = UIColor.black
              self.matematicalExpressionTextField.text = ""


              if self.updateMatematicalQuizUI()
              {
                  self.matematicalExpressionTimerLabel.text = "10"
                  self.startMatematicalTimer()
                  self.matematicalExpressionTextField.isEnabled = true
              }
              else
              {
                  self.matematicalExpressionTextField.isEnabled = false
                  self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ResultSegue", sender: nil)
              }
          }
      }
      func startMatematicalTimer()
      {
          time = 10
          timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateMatematicalTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
      }
      func stopTimer()
      {
          timer.invalidate()
      }

      //text field func


      @objc func updateMatematicalTimer()
      {
          time -= 1
          matematicalExpressionTimerLabel.text = String(time)
          if time <= 0
          {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   stopTimer()
              self.matematicExpression?.playerCorectlyAnswered = false
              self.matematicalExpressionTextField.isEnabled = false
              matematicalExpressionTimerLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
              matematicalExpressionAnswers.append(matematicExpression!)
              nextMatematicalExpression()
          }
      }
      //ContryUI function

      func startContryTimer()
      {
          time = 10
          timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateContryTimer) , userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
      }
      @objc func updateContryTimer()
      {
          time -= 1
          contryQuizTimerLabel.text = String(time)
          if time == 0
          {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   stopTimer()
              contry?.playerCorectlyAnswered = false
              for button in self.contryQuizAnswerChoicesButtons
              {
                  button.isEnabled = false
              }
              contryQuizTimerLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
              contryQuizAnswers.append(contry!)
              nextContry()
          }
      }
      func updateContryQuizUI() -> Bool
      {
          guard !contrys.isEmpty else {return false}

          let number = Int.random(in: 0...contrys.count - 1)
          contry = contrys.remove(at: number)
          contryQuizImageView.image = contry?.image
          updateContryQuizButton(contry: contry!, buttons: contryQuizAnswerChoicesButtons)
          let totalProgress = Float(self.questionIndex)/Float(self.contrysNumber)
          self.progressBar.setProgress(totalProgress, animated: true)

          return true
      }

      func nextContry()
      {
          DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2)
          {
              self.questionIndex += 1
              self.contryQuizTimerLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
              for button in self.contryQuizAnswerChoicesButtons
              {
                  button.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
              }

              for button in self.contryQuizAnswerChoicesButtons
              {
                  button.isEnabled = true
                  button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
              }

              if self.updateContryQuizUI()
              {
                  self.contryQuizTimerLabel.text = "10"
                  self.startContryTimer()
              }
              else
              {
                  for button in self.contryQuizAnswerChoicesButtons
                  {
                      button.isEnabled = false
                  }
                  self.questionIndex = 0
                  self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ResultSegue", sender:nil)
              }
          }
      }
      @IBAction func playerAnswerContryQuiz(_ sender: UIButton) {
          guard let answer = sender.titleLabel?.text else {return}

          for button in self.contryQuizAnswerChoicesButtons
          {
              button.isEnabled = false

          }
          if answer == contry?.answer
          {
              sender.setTitleColor(.green, for: .normal)
              contry?.playerCorectlyAnswered = true
              contryQuizAnswers.append(contry!)
          }
          else
          {
              sender.setTitleColor(.red, for: .normal)
              contry?.playerCorectlyAnswered = false
              contryQuizAnswers.append(contry!)
          }
          stopTimer()
          nextContry()
      }

      //prepare for segue func
      override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

          let resultViewController = segue.destination as? ResultViewController
          if matematicalQuizStackview.isHidden == true
          {
              resultViewController?.contryAnswers = contryQuizAnswers
              resultViewController?.matematicalAnswers = nil

          }
          else
          {
              resultViewController?.matematicalAnswers = matematicalExpressionAnswers
              resultViewController?.contryAnswers = nil
          }

          let resultVC = segue.destination as? ResultViewController
          let savedResultVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SavedResultViewController") as? SavesResultsTableViewController

          resultVC?.delegate = savedResultVC
      }
  ```
- Result ViewController

  ```
  import UIKit

  protocol SavesResultsTableViewControllerDelegate
  {
      func setResult(result: QuizResult?)
  }

  class ResultViewController: UIViewController {

      var delegate: SavesResultsTableViewControllerDelegate?
      var matematicalAnswers:[MatematicalExpression]?
      var contryAnswers:[Image_Contry]?
      var goodAnswersNumber:Double
      {
          //Calcaulating the number of good answer
          var goodAnswers = 0
          if let answers = matematicalAnswers
          {
              for answer in answers
              {
                  if answer.playerCorectlyAnswered == true
                  {
                      goodAnswers += 1
                  }
              }
          }
          if let answers = contryAnswers
          {
              for answer in answers
              {
                  if answer.playerCorectlyAnswered == true
                  {
                      goodAnswers += 1
                  }
              }
          }
          return Double(goodAnswers)
      }
      var result:String
      {
          var results = ""
          if let answers = matematicalAnswers
          {
              //Calculating the answer pourcentage
              let goodAnswerPourcentage = goodAnswersNumber/Double(answers.count)
              if goodAnswerPourcentage < 0.25
              {
                  results = "Stupide"
              }
              else if goodAnswerPourcentage >= 0.25 && goodAnswerPourcentage < 0.5
              {
                  results = "Dans la moyenne"
              }
              else if goodAnswerPourcentage >= 0.50 && goodAnswerPourcentage < 0.75
              {
                  results = "In the averge"
              }
              else if goodAnswerPourcentage >= 0.75 && goodAnswerPourcentage < 1
              {
                  results = "Au dessu de la moyenne"
              }
              else if goodAnswerPourcentage == 1
              {
                  results = "Génie"
              }

          }
          else if let answer = contryAnswers
          {
              let goodAnswerPourcentage = goodAnswersNumber/Double(answer.count)
              if goodAnswerPourcentage < 0.25
              {
                  results = "Stupide"
              }
              else if goodAnswerPourcentage >= 0.25 && goodAnswerPourcentage < 0.5
              {
                  results = "Dans la moyenne"
              }
              else if goodAnswerPourcentage >= 0.50 && goodAnswerPourcentage < 1
              {
                  results = "Au dessu de la moyenne"
              }
              else if goodAnswerPourcentage == 1
              {
                  results = "Génie"
              }

          }

          return results
      }
      var resultText:String
      {
          var resultText = ""
          // define the result
          switch result
          {
          case "Stupide":
              resultText = "Vous avez peut être besoin de reviser vos mathématique ou d'appronfondir vos connaissance générale"
          case "Dans la moyenne":
              resultText = "Vous n'ête pas spécialement intelligent mais pas si idiot."
          case "Au dessu de la moyenne":
              resultText = "Vous êtes supérieur à la moyenne"
          case "Génie":
              resultText = "Vous mériter de controller le monde tellement vos faculté intelectuelle sont élevé"
          default:
              resultText = "Il y a eu une erreur"
          }
          return resultText
      }
      var quizResult:QuizResult
      {
          var type = ""
          if matematicalAnswers != nil
          {
              type = "Matematical Quiz"
          }
          if contryAnswers != nil
          {
              type = "Contry Quiz"
          }
          return QuizResult(quizType:type, result: result)
      }
      @IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: UILabel!
      @IBOutlet weak var resultDescriptionTextView: UITextView!
      @IBOutlet weak var resultTableView: UITableView!

      var tableViewDataSource = ResultTableViewDataSource()

      override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()

          tableViewDataSource.matematicalResults = matematicalAnswers
          tableViewDataSource.contryResults = contryAnswers
          self.resultLabel.text = result
          self.resultDescriptionTextView.text = resultText
          self.resultTableView.dataSource = tableViewDataSource
          delegate?.setResult(result: quizResult)

          // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
      }
  ```
- SavesResultTableViewController

  ```
  import UIKit

  class SavesResultsTableViewController: UITableViewController, SavesResultsTableViewControllerDelegate {

      func setResult(result: QuizResult?)
      {
          if let savedResult = QuizResult.loadFromFile()
          {
              self.results = savedResult
          }
          if let result = result
          {
              self.results.append(result)
          }
      }
      var results = [QuizResult]()
      {

          didSet
          {
              QuizResult.saveToFile(quizResults: results)
          }
      }

      override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
          if let savedResult = QuizResult.loadFromFile()
          {
              self.results = savedResult
          }
          // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
          // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

          // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
          // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem

      }

      // MARK: - Table view data source

      override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
          // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows

          return results.count

      }


      override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
          let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "savedResult", for: indexPath)

          cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1). \(results[indexPath.row].quizType)"
          cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(results[indexPath.row].result)"
          return cell
      }
  ```
- ResultTableViewDataSource

  ```
  import UIKit

  class ResultTableViewDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {

      var matematicalResults:[MatematicalExpression]?
      var contryResults:[Image_Contry]?

      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
          var resultsCount = 0
          if let results = matematicalResults
          {
              resultsCount = results.count
          }
          else if let results = contryResults
          {
              resultsCount = results.count
          }
          return resultsCount
      }

      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
          let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "resultCell") as! ResultTableViewCell

          if let results = matematicalResults
          {
              cell.contryQuizStackView.isHidden = true
              let matematicalExpression = results[indexPath.row]

              cell.matematicalExpressionTrueOrFalseAnswer.textColor = matematicalExpression.playerCorectlyAnswered == true ? UIColor.green:UIColor.red

              cell.updateMatematicalExpressionStackViewContent(matematicalExpression: matematicalExpression.expression , trueOrFalse: matematicalExpression.playerCorectlyAnswered == true ? "✔︎":"✖︎")

          }
          else if let results = contryResults
          {
              cell.matematicalStackView.isHidden = true
              let contry = results[indexPath.row]

              cell.contryTrueOrFalseAnswer.textColor = contry.playerCorectlyAnswered == true ? UIColor.green:UIColor.red

              cell.updateContryStackViewContent(image: contry.image, trueOrFalse: contry.playerCorectlyAnswered == true ? "✔︎":"✖︎")

          }
          return cell
      }
  ```
- ResultTableViewCell

  ```
  {
      @IBOutlet weak var contryQuizStackView: UIStackView!
      @IBOutlet weak var contryImage: UIImageView!
      @IBOutlet weak var contryTrueOrFalseAnswer: UILabel!


      @IBOutlet weak var matematicalStackView: UIStackView!
      @IBOutlet weak var matematicalExpressionLabel: UILabel!
      @IBOutlet weak var matematicalExpressionTrueOrFalseAnswer: UILabel!


      func updateContryStackViewContent(image:UIImage, trueOrFalse:String)
      {
          contryImage.image = image
          contryTrueOrFalseAnswer.text = trueOrFalse
      }
      func updateMatematicalExpressionStackViewContent(matematicalExpression: String, trueOrFalse: String)
      {
          matematicalExpressionLabel.text = matematicalExpression
          matematicalExpressionTrueOrFalseAnswer.text = trueOrFalse

      }
  }
  ```
- MatematicalExpression

  ```
  import Foundation
  struct MatematicalExpression {
      var expression:String
      var answer:String
      var playerCorectlyAnswered = false
  }
  ```
- Image_Contry

  ```
  import UIKit
  import Foundation
  struct Image_Contry
  {
      var image:UIImage
      var answer:String
      var answerPossibility:[String]
      var playerCorectlyAnswered = false


  }
  ```
- QuizResult

  ```
  import Foundation

  class QuizResult: Codable
  {
      var quizType:String
      var result:String
      static var documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
      static var archiveURL = QuizResult.documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("QuizResult").appendingPathExtension("plist")
      init(quizType:String,result:String)
      {
          self.quizType = quizType
          self.result = result
      }

      static func saveToFile(quizResults:[QuizResult])
      {
          let quizResultEncoder = PropertyListEncoder()
          let encodedQuizResult = try? quizResultEncoder.encode(quizResults)
          try? encodedQuizResult?.write(to: archiveURL)
      }
      static func loadFromFile() -> [QuizResult]?
      {
          let quizResultDecoder = PropertyListDecoder()

          if let retrivedQuizResults = try? Data(contentsOf: archiveURL)
          {
              if let decodedQuizResults = try? quizResultDecoder.decode(Array<QuizResult>.self, from: retrivedQuizResults)
              {
                  return decodedQuizResults
              }
          }
          return nil
      }
  }
  ```
- UpdateContryQuizButton

  ```
  import UIKit

  // It was a test to see if I can put function in other file
  func updateContryQuizButton(contry:Image_Contry,buttons:[UIButton])
  {
      var answerPossibilitys = contry.answerPossibility

      for button in buttons
      {
          let number = Int.random(in: 0...answerPossibilitys.count - 1)
          button.setTitle(answerPossibilitys.remove(at: number), for: .normal)
      }

  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

First of all I want to mention that I used Swift 4.2/Xcode 10.1 to write this answer.

You should have this `extension` in your project, `count(of:)` returns count of elements in a sequence that fit to your statement:

```
extension Sequence {
    func count(where predicate: (Element) -> Bool) -> Int {
        return reduce(0) { currentResult, currentItem in
            return currentResult + (predicate(currentItem) ? 1 : 0)
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I can see in your code, `MatematicalExpression` and `Image_Contry` are very similar. You can declare a protocol that demonstrates this feature:

```
protocol AnswerDataProvider {
    var answer: String { get }
    var playerCorectlyAnswered: Bool { get }
}
```

`MatematicalExpression` and `Image_Contry` should implement this protocol:

```
extension MatematicalExpression: AnswerDataProvider { }

extension Image_Contry: AnswerDataProvider { }
```

With this `extension` you can easily get count of correct answers:

```
extension Sequence where Element: AnswerDataProvider {
    var countOfCorrectAnswers: Int {
        return count { $0.playerCorectlyAnswered }
    }
}
```

You have a lot of similar strings, use this `enum` to solve the problem:

```
enum Comment {
    case stupid
    case belowAverage
    case average
    case aboveAverage
    case genius

    var translation: String {
        switch self {
        case .stupid:
            return "Stupide"
        case .belowAverage:
            return "Dans la moyenne"
        case .average:
            return "In the averge"
        case .aboveAverage:
            return "Au dessu de la moyenne"
        case .genius:
            return "Génie"
        }
    }
}
```

With this `enum` you will have only 1 property for `matematicalAnswers` and `contryAnswers` in `ResultViewController`:

```
enum Answers {
    case matematical([MatematicalExpression])
    case country([Image_Contry])
}
```

I guess these functions can help you to solve different problems:

```
extension Answers {
    var countOfAllAnswers: Int {
        switch self {
        case .matematical(let matematicalExpressions):
            return matematicalExpressions.count
        case .country(let contryAnswers):
            return contryAnswers.count
        }
    }

    var countOfCorrectAnswers: Int {
        switch self {
        case .matematical(let matematicalExpressions):
            return matematicalExpressions.countOfCorrectAnswers
        case .country(let contryAnswers):
            return contryAnswers.countOfCorrectAnswers
        }
    }

    var goodAnswerPercentage: Double {
        return Double(countOfCorrectAnswers)/Double(countOfAllAnswers)
    }

    var percentageWithComments: [(Double, Comment)] {
        switch self {
        case .matematical:
            return [
                (0.0, .stupid),
                (0.25, .belowAverage),
                (0.5, .average),
                (0.75, .aboveAverage),
                (1.0, .genius)
            ]
        case .country:
            return [
                (0.0, .stupid),
                (0.25, .belowAverage),
                (0.5, .aboveAverage),
                (1.0, .genius)
            ]
        }
    }

    var result: String {
        let goodAnswerPercentageValue = goodAnswerPercentage
        return percentageWithComments.reversed().first {
            return goodAnswerPercentageValue >= $0.0
        }?.1.translation ?? ""
    }

    var quizResult: QuizResult {
        let type: String
        switch self {
        case .matematical:
            type = "Matematical Quiz"
        case .country:
            type = "Contry Quiz"
        }
        return QuizResult(quizType: type, result: result)
    }
}
```

In such case `ResultViewController` will be shorter:

```
class ResultViewController: UIViewController {

    var answers: Answers?
    var goodAnswersNumber: Double {
        return Double(answers?.countOfCorrectAnswers ?? 0)
    }

    var result: String {
        return answers?.result ?? ""
    }

    var quizResult: QuizResult {
        return answers?.quizResult ?? QuizResult(quizType: "", result: result)
    }

    //Other functions and properties
}
```

You can try to refactor other controllers with the similar protocols and enums.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I dont understand the "where predicate: (Element)"

Comment: @C.Calvinno this function returns count of items that fit some statement. In your case you can use it for the count of correct answers. For more information check these links: https://forums.swift.org/t/count-where-on-sequence/11186 and  https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0220-count-where.md .

Comment: Hello @C.Calvinno. Do you still have questions regarding the `func count(where:)`?

Comment: No ,thanks, I had some question about the where keyword but I find the information on the internet. Now I gradually understand your way of coding and change mine